# Android override AlertDialog onClick

Tags: java, android

I use this code in a separate non activity class for my AlertDialogs

```
class Utility {
static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String title, String message) {
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I want to override the onClick in one of my activity classes but I don't know how.

Comment: Use interface for getting click on your activity

Comment: or you can use Custom dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the click listener to the method and use a different listener for your `Activity`. You will have two methods, one with the default version and the other with the `OnClickListener` customizable:

```
class Utility {
    static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String title, String message, OnClickListener listener) {
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", listener);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String title, String message) {
        alertDialogShow(context, title, message, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about passing `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` to method as parameter.

```
   static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String title, String message,DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", onClickListener);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```